# How to know when all ledgers are updated?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Version: V1.4.0

I have a channel with multi peers. If I send a transaction and commit success in a peer, is there have any way to know when all ledgers are updated?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, Endorsements field of the transaction, however I am not sure which API call you need to make to get the data you want.